# Calling void methods from main method, cannot pass arguments within void methods

Tags: java, arrays, arguments

my teacher asked us to create an additive prime program for my computer science class. I have created all my void methods, and believe to have all the math logic figured out. However, when I try to pass arguments into the instances of my methods within my main method, It gives me an error saying:

> it can not find the variable in this case variable 'x'

```
package additiveprimes;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 * @author talarik048
 */
public class AdditivePrimes {

public static void main(String[] args){ 

    AdditivePrimes additivePrime = new AdditivePrimes();
    additivePrime.userInput(x);
    additivePrime.isPrime(x);
    additivePrime.numArray(x);

}

public void userInput(String x){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try{
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        x = sc.nextLine();
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Error, try again: ");
        x = sc.nextLine();
    }

}

public void isPrime(String x){
    this.userInput(x);
    boolean prime = true;
    int y = Integer.parseInt(x);


    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){

        if(y % i == 0){
            prime = false;
            break;
        }

        if(prime){
            System.out.println("Your number is prime...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your number is not prime...");
        }
    }

}

public void numArray(String x){
    this.userInput(x);
    String[] strArray = x.split("\\s+");
    boolean prime = true;

    int[] numbArray = new int[strArray.length];
    for(int j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++){
        try{
        numbArray[j] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[j]);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }


       for(int i = 0; i < numbArray.length; i++){ 
       int sum = (Arrays.stream(numbArray).sum());
       if(sum % i == 0){
           prime = false;
           break;
       }
       if(prime){
           System.out.println("Your number is an additive prime...");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Your number is not an additive prime...");
       }
     }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: "x" is not defined.

Comment: What you are trying to do won't work. You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value. Your userInput Method should **return** the input so that you can use them. You cannot pass a String to that method and then change that string inside the userInput method and have that an effect outside of the method.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For future please  post a [MCVE] or SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem. 
This will increase your chances of getting a helpful answer (and also may help you find the problem).

Comment: Also something that is unrelated to your Problem: Your catching of NumberFormatException is pretty useless as no line in the try block will ever throw it if you just use nextLine().

Answer (score 2):

I think you wanted to RETURN a value from `userInput`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    AdditivePrimes additivePrime = new AdditivePrimes();
    String x = additivePrime.userInput();
    additivePrime.isPrime(x);
    additivePrime.numArray(x);

}

public String userInput(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = null;
    try{
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        x = sc.nextLine();
    } catch(Exception e){// see  OH GOD SPIDERS comment
        System.out.println("Error, try again: ");
        x = sc.nextLine();//this is not a good way for a retry
    }
    return x;
}
```

Alternatively you could make `x` a field.

Answer (score 1):

Your methods accept a string as an argument, but you have not passed any. You need to initialize `x` in main.

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    AdditivePrimes additivePrime = new AdditivePrimes();
    String x= "55";
    additivePrime.userInput(x);
    additivePrime.isPrime(x);
    additivePrime.numArray(x);

}
```

**Note**

Although the above code fixes your current issue. It doesn't seem to be the correct way to use this class. You should probably be calling `.userInput()` method and getting the userInput then passing it to your other methods.

You could probably change your overall class to

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    AdditivePrimes additivePrime = new AdditivePrimes();
    String x = additivePrime.userInput();
    additivePrime.isPrime(x);
    additivePrime.numArray(x);

}

public String userInput(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = null;
    try{
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        x = sc.nextLine();
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Error, try again: ");
        x = sc.nextLine();
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt make sense to pass string to the userInput method....Consider the situation prior to answering.

Comment: @Os. yea I know. I was just solving his original problem. But to fix his whole class is another two cents :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined x as anything before using it. Try defining x. In this case since your arguments are strings, I recommend...

```
String x = new String();
```